# Does bash -c or zsh -c have a limit on a string it executes?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, zsh

It appears that there is a 240 character limit on the expanded string.  This quick test works for short file names, but does not work for longer names.

```
ls | xargs -I {} zsh -c "echo '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------{}'; echo '==============================================================================={}'"
```

Is there a way to expand this limit on Mac and/or Linux?

Comment: If there's a limit it would be in the millions, not 240.

Comment: Do you mean limit on [xargs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), on bash or zsh ... or limits on file/file path names?  There are *DEFINITELY* limits on the latter.  See [MAX_PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation)

Comment: There's no limit in zsh. If you execute `zsh -c "echo 'really long string'"` it works fine. So the problem seems to be with `xargs`

Comment: Also, the problem happens even without `zsh`. Just `echo longstring | xargs -I {} echo '----manytimes---{}'` demonstrates it

Answer (score 4):

No, bash and zsh have no such limit.

Instead, here's `man xargs` (emphasis mine):

> ```
> -I replstr
> ```
>
> Execute utility for each input line, replacing one or more occurrences of replstr in up to replacements (or 5 if no -R flag is specified) arguments to utility with the entire line of input.  The resulting arguments, after replacement is done, **will not be allowed to grow beyond 255 bytes**; this is implemented by concatenating as much of the argument containing replstr as possible, to the constructed arguments to utility, up to 255 bytes.  The 255 byte limit does not apply to arguments to utility which do not contain replstr, and furthermore, no replacement will be done on utility itself.  Implies -x.

The [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-216.60.1/xargs/strnsubst.c.auto.html) is more direct:

> Replaces str with a string consisting of str with match replaced with `replstr` as many times as can be done before the constructed string is maxsize bytes large.

So if the string is already 255+ characters long, the number of times it can replace the string is zero.

This is not a problem in practice since you would never use the `replstr` in the argument to `*sh -c` due to the security and robustness issues it causes.

Instead, pass the arguments separately and reference them from the shell command:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for arg; do echo "Received: $arg"; done' _
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to do the concatenation the way it describes. When the argument grows beyond 255 bytes, it just reverts to the argument with `replstr` still in it.

Comment: It's a bit ambiguous but the source code is more explicit

Comment: Thank you, everybody, for the clarification.  It is, indeed XARG limit.  It does appear to be around 240 and not 255 as per this quick test.  Adding 1 more character to the string will break it (even though it would've resulted in 250 total). echo 1234556789012345678901234 | xargs -I {} echo '{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'

Comment: @FlarePlf Your string is already 250 long, you wrote the first `5` twice

Comment: Lol, thank you, nice catch!  Makes way more sense.

Comment: Special thanks to @thatotherguy  for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the operating system, not on the shell. You can find this limit on Linux-like systems by

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

On my platform, this is 32000.

Actually, this is not just the limit for a single command argument, but for the whole command line.